# Database File 'is being used by another process' when all connections are closed

Tags: java, database, connection, data-access-object

I am developing a system which uses a database access object (DAO) to link between the program and database. All connections must be made through this class, using `getConnection()`. However, I have a reset option which overrides the database file in the user's file system with one inside the application itself (i.e. in its jar when deployed). This `reset()` feature causes an exception saying that the database is already in use.

```
java.nio.file.FileSystemException: C:\iMProve\improveDB.accdb: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
```

With research, this means that the connections have not been closed properly. However, I will show you the whole code for this DAO class if you can spot possibly where lies the problem.

```
public class DAO {
    private static final String dbDir = "C://iMProve";
    private static final String dbName = "improveDB.accdb";
    private static final String dbUrl = "jdbc:ucanaccess://" + dbDir + "//"+ dbName;
    private ObservableList<Connection> allConnections = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    public DAO() { //constructor - called when object is made
        try {
            Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver");
        } catch(ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Cannot load ucanaccess driver");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        File directory = new File(dbDir);
        if(!directory.exists()) //create directory if not already
            directory.mkdir();
        File database = new File(dbDir + "//" + dbName);
        if(!database.exists()) { //copy the database file into user's file system - if not already
            try {
                Files.copy(DAO.class.getResourceAsStream(dbName), database.toPath(), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
            } catch(IOException ex) {ex.printStackTrace();}
        }
    }
    public void reset() {
        File database = new File(dbDir + "//" + dbName);
        try {
            Files.copy(DAO.class.getResourceAsStream(dbName), database.toPath(), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public Connection getConnection() { //create a connection to the database
        Connection conn = null; 
        try {
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
        allConnections.add(conn);
        return conn;
    }
    public void closeConnections() {
        for(Connection conn: allConnections) {
            if(conn!=null) {
                try {
                    conn.close();
                    System.out.println("closed");
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The constructor simply copies the database from the application into the user's file system if not there already.

The `getConnection()` method connects to the database.

Calling `reset()` on its own produces that error, so by adding the connections to a static collection we can closing each and every connection, using `closeConnections()`.

**Note:** These connections should already be closed anyways because we always a try-with-resources.
For example:

```
try (
            Connection conn = dao.getConnection();
            PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT Title FROM Theory WHERE Grade <= ?");
    ) {
```

And although we have two levels for closing connections

1. try-with-resources
2. `closeConnections()` method

They still are ineffective. When calling closeConnections(), we still get outputs of

```
closed
closed
```

even when connections have been used inside try-with-resources blocks.
And even *with* `closeConnections()`, we still get the same error:

```
java.nio.file.FileSystemException: C:\iMProve\improveDB.accdb: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
```

Comment: Why to not use `try-with-resource` to automatically close the connections? It's possible that the driver is holding the database open, even after the connections are closed for performance reasons

Comment: So, not bad for a "guess".  If you have a look at [this post from their help forums](https://sourceforge.net/p/ucanaccess/discussion/help/thread/4539a56c/), you should also include `((UcanaccessConnection) conn).unloadDB();` as part of your close operation (I looked at the connection properties, but I don't think they suit your needs)

Comment: thank you! that did the trick, calling `unloadDB()` from a random `Connection` in the `closeConnections()` method did the trick. However, why do you need to do this when all streams are closed? Also, why are the streams not already closed with the try-with-resource prior to `closeConnections()`?

Comment: If you read the linked post, ucanaccess will keep the file open (and some other resources) for a short period in order to improve the performance for situations where connections are opened and closed in quick succession